# Facebook python marketing API AttributeError

Tags: python, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to use Facebook Marketing API through its python package facebookapi.

here's a code snippet:

```
from facebookads.adobjects.customaudience import CustomAudience

audience = CustomAudience(parent_id='act_10336...')
audience[CustomAudience.Field.subtype] = CustomAudience.Subtype.custom
audience[CustomAudience.Field.name] = 'My new CA'
audience[CustomAudience.Field.description] = 'People who bought on my website'

audience.remote_create()
```

It is taken directly from Facebook's example for custom audience creation given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience).

I put the appropriate AD_ACCOUNT_ID in the second line.

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'
```

After much investigation I found that this line from api.py returns None, which I think is at the heart of the problem:

```
FacebookAdsApi.get_default_api()
```

In fact, any api call I tried to perform returned a similar error.

Anyone knows anything about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't bootstrap the API? 
Try this:

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects

my_app_id = '<APP_ID>'
my_app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>'
my_access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
proxies = {'http': '<HTTP_PROXY>', 'https': '<HTTPS_PROXY>'} # add proxies if needed
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token, proxies)
```

Comment: how can we generate access_token?

Comment: getting error of ""message": "Invalid OAuth access token.""

Comment: @MitulShah Get a short lived token first with `FB.login()`, then ask for a long lived token with the short lived one by `GET /oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}`. Repeat the process when the token expires.